# Mythtv backend install problems

Tags: mysql, container, mythtv

I am trying to install mythtv on Proxmox as Ubuntu 22.04 container. I had fallowed instructions on web and video on [youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8GY3.png)

I ended with command:

sudo apt-get install mysql-server mythtv-backend mythtv-database

But after that I got only one windows asking about mythweb, so when it was finished I added user typing

sudo usermod -a -G mythtv mythtv

I had logout and wanted to configure mysql with

sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf

but the file looks empty like this

[image: like this]

I tried without doing anything to that file but I can not login typing

ssh -X mythtv@192.168.1.212 /usr/bin/mythtv-setup

(even changing user to sudo, root, changing passwords). What should I do? I am not so good in it.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you're trying to install MythTV on a headless server, hence wanting to run mythtv-setup via SSH, yes?

I'm not familiar with Proxmox, but I also have MythTV set up on a headless server running Ubuntu server 20.04, so maybe my setup will be instructive.

My own my.cnf file looks exactly like yours, so I would assume everything is more or less OK there.

For reasons I've never really got my head round, I've also struggled to run mythtv-setup as the mythtv user. I've just logged in as my normal user. You need to add your own user account (on the server) to the mythtv group, but it should mostly work OK once you've done that.

I've also used the -Y option rather than the -X option on SSH to be able to run the mythtv-setup graphically, though I'm not sure that that makes any difference.

So try tweaking your SSH command to this:

ssh -Y 192.168.1.212 /usr/bin/mythtv-setup

(assuming your user account on the server and the machine you're sshing in from have the same name) and see what happens.

Comment: No luck. I found some answers on   https://forum.mythtv.org/viewtopic.php?p=15073#p15073   but again I get into login part. After   ssh -Y 192.168.1.212 /usr/bin/mythtv-setup  I got  "The authenticity of host '192.168.1.212 (192.168.1.212)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:iRtxpdNSsw6Eb2SiFPaPsh1egKyuuo/tHkwnfoG57cg. This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?"  I had answer yes  and got  "Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.212' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts"  but password and ED25519 didn work

Comment: Can you ssh into your server just normally without trying to do the mythtv setup? I wonder if the problem is with your ssh credentials rather than with mythtv?

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems in other cases. ssh demands that you have ssh-askpass or ssh-askpass-gnome installed on the client machine that you are trying to login from to be able to pass on credentials to the remote machine